# Transbordo Localización

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab, operations-research, mathematical-spanish

[image]

If someone could help I will thank him or her a lot, its a problem of linear programming, im taking a course in Spanish, but I don't understand it , they are using Excel solver and want me to use Matlab to get the results.[

[image]

Comment: I don't know Matlab, but it seems to have a solver for such problems. Your procedure just has to read the data ($c_j$ and $d_{ij}$) from the Excel file, and I think it needs some conversion, because the Matlab solver expects a vector for variables and coefficients instead of vector + matrix. I don't understand the data format in the Excel file, there are $c$, but I don't see any $d$. So what do you need, a translation of the description?

Comment: Use [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/El%20problema%20de%20localizaci%C3%B3n%20de%20planta%20pupede%20caractezirse%20de%20la%20siguiente%20forma%3A%20ubicar%20localiziciones%20de%20centros%20para%20atenci%C3%B3n%20de%20clientes%20a%20fin%20de%20minizar%20los%20costos%20de%20opraci%C3%B3n%20y%20atenci%C3%B3n.%20Tenemos%20%E2%80%9Cn%E2%80%9D%20ubiciciones%20posibles%20y%20%E2%80%9Cm%E2%80%9D%20clientes%20que%20requieren%20atenci%C3%B3n%20%E2%80%A6) and figure the rest out by yourself, I suggest.